# Gulp using gulp-jade with gulp-data

Tags: json, node.js, pug, gulp

I'm trying to use gulp-data with gulp-jade in my workflow but I'm getting an error related to the gulp-data plugin.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
  jade = require('gulp-jade'),
  data = require('gulp-data'),
  path = require('path'),
  sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
  prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  process = require('child_process');

  gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);

  // Watch task
  gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('*.jade', ['jade']);
    gulp.watch('public/css/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('public/js/*.js', ['js']);
  });

  var getJsonData = function(file, cb) {
    var jsonPath = './data/' + path.basename(file.path) + '.json';
    cb(require(jsonPath))
  };

  // Jade task
  gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src('*.jade')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(data(getJsonData))
    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Build/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
  });

  ...

  // Browser-sync task
  gulp.task('browser-sync', ['jade', 'sass', 'js'], function() {
    return browserSync.init(null, {
    server: {
      baseDir: 'Build'
    }
  });
});
```

And this is a basic json file, named index.jade.json

```
{
  "title": "This is my website"
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in plugin 'gulp-data'
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting error because in `getJsonData` you pass required data as first argument to the callback. That is reserved for possible errors.

In your case the callback isn't needed. Looking at [gulp-data usage example](https://github.com/colynb/gulp-data#usage) this should work:

```
.pipe(data(function(file) {
  return require('./data/' + path.basename(file.path) + '.json');
}))
```

Full example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var data = require('gulp-data');
var path = require('path');
var fs   = require('fs');

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('*.jade')
    .pipe(data(function(file) {
      return require('./data/' + path.basename(file.path) + '.json');
    }))
    .pipe(jade({ pretty: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

Use this if you're running the task on `gulp.watch`:

```
.pipe(data(function(file) {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/' + path.basename(file.path) + '.json'));
}))
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error anymore but if I type `p= title` in `index.jade` I get only an empty `p` tag in the generated html file. I checked the gulp-jade documentation and the reason I used the `geJsonData` variable is because it what they recommend [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-jade#use-with-gulp-data-https-www-npmjs-org-package-gulp-data-)

Comment: That's odd. It works for me. Example in gulp-jade is outdated.

Comment: Just figured out that it is working actually but only when I run `gulp` command in terminal. Is there any way to get the object content on task run and inject the data live?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How else are you running gulp tasks?

Comment: Sorry for my newbie questions and thank you for helping me. Now I type `gulp`, I start typing `p Hello World`, hit `cmd+s` and the output html file gets the `p` tag with its content. But if I type `p= title` to get that in the generated file I have to hit `ctrl+c` to stop gulp and then run `gulp` again.

Comment: Could you try `return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/' + path.basename(file.path) + '.json'));` and see if it works? I think you're running watch and because require calls are cached, changes to json don't show up unless you restart the task.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Because of that the example has been fixed: https://github.com/phated/gulp-jade#use-with-gulp-data

Comment: Check if your JSON exists or return default config:

`var config = {
      "title": "This is my website"
    }

    .pipe(data(function(file) {
        var pat = './data/' + path.basename(file.path) + '.json'
        if (fs.existsSync(pat)) {
            return require(pat);
        } else {
            return config;
        }
    }))`