# Compiling gulp-jade with data

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to render data from a file (eventually i will generate the data dynamically, or follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313107/gulp-using-gulp-jade-with-gulp-data) to use a data file) into jade using gulp. This is what I have, but I know I have made a silly mistake (i'm not an expert in jade yet) as I ever get runtime errors or `undefined` in the compiled html. Would welcome advice

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  rotm: [
    {title: "title 1", comment: "comment 1"},
    {title: "title 2", comment: "comment 1"},
    {title: "title 3", comment: "comment 1"},
    {title: "title 4", comment: "comment 1"}
  ]
};
```

gulp.coffee

```
config      = require "./config.js"
gulp.task 'jade', ->
  gulp.src paths.jade
  .pipe run.changed "./", extension : ".jade"
  .pipe run.plumber()
  .pipe run.jade pretty : true, data : config
  .pipe run.rename extname : ".hbs"
  .pipe gulp.dest ""
  .pipe reload stream : true, once : true
```

home.jade

```
  each r in rotm
    h1 {{r.title}}
    p.comment {r.comment}
```

result

```
<h1>{r.title}</h1>
<p class="comment">{r.comment}</p>
<h1>{r.title}</h1>
<p class="comment">{r.comment}</p>
<h1>{r.title}</h1>
<p class="comment">{r.comment}</p>
<h1>{r.title}</h1>
```

Comment: `data : config.rotm` -> `data : config` ?

Comment: Is this correct? I haven't ever used `gulp-jade` like you're trying, but the guide on [repository](https://github.com/phated/gulp-jade#use-with-gulp-data) says you should use [gulp-data](https://github.com/colynb/gulp-data). Or what @Heikki makes sense too, since you're iterating `rotm` inside `home.jade`, but the data is only array stored in `rotm`, not `rotm` itself.

Comment: @Heikki: updated the question your input, which gave me some output - shown.

Comment: http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @heikki I now have

```
  each r in rotm
    h1 #{r.title}
    p.comment #{r.comment}
```